# scrlayer-notecolumn outputs lots of TRACE messages

Tags: koma-script

Using scrlayer-notecolumn outputs lots of TRACE messages in the command line. (How) can I turn these off?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\DeclareNewNoteColumn{notes}

\begin{document}
    
    Some real text.
    \makenote[notes]{Blub blub}
    \clearnotecolumn[notes]
\end{document}
```

The command line output contains these lines, which I would like to get rid of:

```
TRACE (slnc): clearnote=1, abspage=0, until page=1, process=\z@ , pagetotal=0.0
pt, topskip=11.0pt
TRACE (slnc): add \clearpage
TRACE (slnc): 1<=1?
Soll: -2.6pt
Ist:  -2.6pt
...
TRACE (slnc): clearnote=2, abspage=1, until page=1, process=\reserved@a , paget
otal=0.0pt, topskip=11.0pt
```

In my actual document (a long thesis), hundreds of these messages are produced, completely spamming the command line.

Comment: You would have to regenerate the sty from the sources without the trace option. You could make a feature request for a switch.